# Criando diretório no Angular

Tags: angular, front-end

Tenho o código no Angular e gostaria de exportar essa planilha para um diretório específico. Alguém, pode me ajudar?

```
exportSheet() {
    this.loading = true;

    var sDate: string = new DatePipe('en').transform(this.form.value.startDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00');
    var eDate: string = new DatePipe('en').transform(this.form.value.endDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy 23:59:59');

    this.reportService.getExportEventTypeAlarms(this.form.value.eventType != null ? this.form.value.eventType : "",
    this.form.value.local != null ? this.form.value.local : "", this.form.value.groupby,
    sDate != null ? sDate : "",
    eDate != null ? eDate : ""
    ).subscribe((result: any) => {
        let ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(result);
        let wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "EventosPorTipo");
        XLSX.writeFile(wb, "EventosPorTipo.xlsx");

        this.loading = false;
        
    });

}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

Angular roda sempre no cliente, não no servidor. Por isso, não tem como você pré-determinar a pasta de destino de um download. Quem controla isso é o browser, por motivos de segurança. Se não fosse assim, alguém poderia criar uma página que força um download de um código malicioso para uma pasta específica sem o usuário saber.